# Submit Slurm Jobs using Python

Tags: python, bash, hpc, sbatch

I have `foo.sh` as below

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -A research
#SBATCH -p long
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 24
#SBATCH -t 2-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --exclude=node37

module load Gaussian/09revC

export GAUSS_SCRDIR=/scratch/$USER.$SLURM_JOBID
/bin/mkdir -p $GAUSS_SCRDIR

g09 $1

/bin/rm -rf $GAUSS_SCRDIR
```

And I call `foo.sh` from another bash file called `submit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sbatch foo.sh 00_molecule_name_some_method.com
sbatch foo.sh 01_molecule_name_some_method.com
sbatch foo.sh 02_molecule_name_some_method.com
```

This submits multiple jobs.

I want to change `submit.sh` to Python file which will call `foo.sh` provide it with argument which will go to `$1` in `foo.sh`, Python should not wait for the jobs to get completed.

Also `molecule_name` and `some_method` are variables which I will provide in for loop

template Python script `submit.py`

```
for molecule_name in molecules:
    for some_method in methods:
        foo.sh molecule_name some_method
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/scratch’: Permission denied
PGFIO/stdio: No such file or directory
PGFIO-F-/OPEN/unit=11/error code returned by host stdio - 2.
File name = /scratch/USERNAME./Gau-41212.inp
In source file ml0.f, at line number 181
PGFIO/stdio: No such file or directory
PGFIO-F-/OPEN/unit=11/error code returned by host stdio - 2.
File name = /scratch/USERNAME./Gau-41213.inp
In source file ml0.f, at line number 181
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess
for molecule_name in molecules:
    for some_method in methods:
        command1 = subprocess.Popen(['foo.sh', molecule_name, some_method])
```

Comment: So document says this will spawn child process in new process. This will not halt the python script right ?

Comment: No, it will execute the command provided which will start in background in new process.